# Approve of him vs approve him

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I have to confess that before I came across the construct **approve of him** I didn't  know it even existed. The only version I knew was **approve him**.

Studying the **approve**'s definitions in the dictionaries cited in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/approve) I concluded that **approve someone or something** has to do with the transitive use of the mentioned verb whereas **approve of someone or something** is related to its intransitive use.

The usage note of **approve of**, according to [Collins COBUILD English Usage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/approve) states:

> Be Careful!
>
> Don't say that you **approve to** someone or something.

My question is why? Would you please let me know this?

In rest I think I understand why it's OK to say:

> Stefan approved of the whole affair.

whereas

> The directors quickly approved of the new deal.

Is not OK. That's because using **of** in this sentence, the sentence will get the first meaning which is not appropriate in this context.

Comment: To approve *of* = to give one's approbation.  To approve: to give one's OK, "give it the green light", to authorize.   *Approve *to*" is simply the wrong preposition; I wouldn't know what was meant.  The sentence about the directors is, IMO, not the clearest example of how not to use the word. Here's one: "*The municipality approved of the construction permit."

Comment: "Approve of" and "Approve" have different semantics not just transitivity or not. I could approve an application without approving of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand correctly.

- Steven approved of the whole affair.
  Intransitive, takes indirect object, so "of" is correct.
- The directors quickly approved the new deal.
  Transitive, takes direct object, adding "of" would change it to intransitive, which is not what you meant.